# Determing timestamp of a photo of the stars using a plate solver

Tags: photography, time, astrometry

[This](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14497/how-accurately-can-you-tell-the-time-using-a-photo-of-the-stars) question from 2016 seems to suggest that you need a powerful telescope to get a photo of the stars in such a way that you can use their proper motion to get a timestamp. If this is possible, how would you do it?

For example, Astrometry.net provides a decent first guess given an image of the stars, taken from Earth with a commercial camera. Their own publication [says](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.2233.pdf) that using tools like [WCSFits](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/2006ASPC..351..204M) can provide a better starfield fit to pixels, given Astrometry.net's first guess. Based on this fit, is it possible to get a reasonably good UTC timestamp, if I exclusively work with images taken post-2000, and I know where each image was taken from (i.e. the lat/lon coordinates on Earth)?

Comment: The star with the highest PM is Bernard's Star, at 10 arcsec per year, or .01" per day.  You would be hard pressed to discern a day's movement from atmospheric effects, let alone anything down to the minute or second.

Comment: Ah, I see. I figured it was worth a shot asking here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

#### Asteroids!

There are [**almost a million** identified minor planets out there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_planets) with pretty well characterized orbital motion.

Your plate solver will give you two things - a coordinate system for your frame, and a way to begin to identify objects that don't correspond to stars.

Once you've got a few candidates, you can use [Skyfield's Kepler orbit propagator](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/kepler-orbits.html) to quickly get approximate locations of all of them and search for candidates.

Then for those candidates use JPL's [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/) to get much more accurate predictions for their positions as a function of time.

You are well on your way to getting some kind of timestamp, assuming you can find two or three asteroids in your exposure.

#### Satellites!

There are lots and lots of Earth-orbiting satellites that criss-cross astronomical plates in addition to those pesky Starlinks. Some are in MEO (e.g. GPS, GLONASS, BeiDou, Galileo, there are others) and a whole bunch of them are in GEO. Most of them are in the equatorial plane, but [some make big figure eights](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37454/12102)

[image]

For these you use [two line element sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set) and propagate those as a function of time to look for candidates. Again you need several to be sure.

#### Galilean satellites of Jupiter!

This "clock" is [how the speed of light was first measured](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light#Measurement) but alone I don't think you can get an unambiguous measurement - three of the four are in resonance so the frequency of repeats may be too high unless you have a specific time window in mind. Of course if you can also see the stars behind jupiter at the same time, then you have both a "fast clock" and a "slow clock" (Jupiter's orbital motion, from Skyfield or Horizons) so that might work out.

Comment: Aren't asteroids dimmer than stars? I'm trying to think of a way to do this elegantly - maybe plate solve and subtract the sources using Gaia or something similar. However I don't know how I'd differentiate between asteroids, satellites, and noise given only a single image.

Comment: @requiemman I didn't fully appreciate that this must be done with a *single* image. Asteroids are dimmer than the brightest stars, but starting at say +6 magnitude and higher (dimmer) there are plenty of both asteroids and star (more stars than asteroids of course). The problem with a single image is that it's hard to be certain of the identity of any object that's not where a star is known to be. Usually the speed and direction of motion is used to confirm the identity of an asteroid. I suppose if you have a plate with a lot of high proper motion stars in one field going different directions

Comment: @requiemman you could do a global plate solve, remove low order field distortion and match all the residual errors to proper motions to get an approximate timestamp. Mostly you'll see parallax motion which is repetitive yearly, so the right balance between parallax and proper motion might work in your favor. You didn't mention if one gets to choose where to point the telescope to make the single image, or if it is some random, undocumented "found" plate in some old filing cabinet in a storage room.